# a special matrix inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matrix-equations

Let

$A=\left( \begin{matrix}
   {{A}_{11}} & \ldots  & {{A}_{1n}}  \\
   \vdots  & \ddots  & \vdots   \\
   {{A}_{n1}} & \cdots  & {{A}_{nn}}  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$ be an invertible matrix,

where

1) the elements in each off-diagonal block $A_{ij} \quad (i\neq j)$ have the same values, and

2) the elements in each diagonal block $A_{ii}$ are not the same values.

3) all elements in $A$ are non-negative,

4) $A$ is a sparse matrix.

Is there an easy way to find the inverse of the matrix $A$, given the inverse of each off-diagonal block ${A_{ii}^{-1}}$?

Comment: how do you know that $A$ is invertible?

Comment: It is assumed that $A^{-1}$ exists.

Comment: Do you mean $A_{ij}$ are matrix blocks, each a constant matrix, with a different constant for each block, and with many zero blocks so that the matrix is sparse? Then my previous comment does not hold.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, each off-diagonal block is a constant matrix. Some are zero matrices, and some are not.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I didn't understand the question at first.

Comment: @mvw, the inverse of each off-diagonal block is given.

Comment: I believe you would rather need the inverses of the diagonal blocks. It looks like one could operate blockwise, but I do not recognize an advantage over treating the matrix as $n\times n$ matrix.

Comment: What are the sizes of the blocks? Are they constant? How large is $n$? Since the off-diagonal blocks are constant matrices, the off-diagonal part of $A$ has low rank (related to $n$) and then you might consider using the Woodbury formula for inverting it.